# Editing/deleting datatable rows in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, wordpress, datatable

I'm in a real pinch....I"ve been tasked with making the datatables on this website editable. Basically, each row needs to have an edit and delete option. One issue is the fact that my datatables are filled via my database table, so if any edits are made or any rows deleted, it would need to affect the database via update or delete.

I've had some issues with these tables on this specific wordpress site, mainly involving column visibility and buttons. However, I'm really having the pressure put on me to have this working by tomorrow and I'm at a loss.

I've seen the Editor plugin on datatables.net but I'm very confused with how to use it in this site. The main things to keep in mind is this is a wordpress site and my table is filled and affected by a database controlled in phpMyAdmin.

I'm very much a novice in this area so any solution that will work is incredibly appreciated.

My database connection and query:

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pw = "password"
$db = "database";

$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);



if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    //echo'success!';
}

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM staging;";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query1);
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM stagingSurvey;";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$query2);
?>
```

My code for the datatables with includes and css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

```
</head>
<body style="background-color:#3A6587";>

<label style="font-weight:bold;">Select the table you would like to view:</label></br>
<select name='tables' id='select-tables'>
<option value="mytable">Survey Test Table</option>
<option value="mytableSurvey">Survey Only</option>   
</select>
</br>


<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#mytable').DataTable({
dom: 'Blfrtip',
buttons: [
'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis'
]
});

$('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Get the column API object
var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

// Toggle the visibility
column.visible( ! column.visible() );
```

} );

```
$('#mytableSurvey').DataTable({
dom: 'Blfrtip',
buttons: [
'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis'
]
});
$('.dataTable').wrap('<div class="dataTables_scroll" />');




$(document).on('change' , '#select-tables', function(){
var table = $(this).val();
$('#' + table +'_wrapper').show();
$('[id$="_wrapper"]').not('#' + table +'_wrapper').hide();
});
$("#select-tables").trigger("change");

});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried their [generator](https://editor.datatables.net/generator/)?

Comment: I haven't actually. Do you have any experience using that on WordPress?

Comment: None, however the setup seems simple enough. They write to simply change the included php files to connect to your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but a way to point you out to a solution without using dattables editor. I have done it like this in the past.

If you have some experience with ajax you can create a row in datatables with a button in which you include an attribute with the row ID. Then set up a onclick event to send a ajax trequest to a function that deletes the row with that ID from database.

For the editing I used https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ which has a very simple API.

In case you want some more help I can try help you through [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147510/room-for-buxbeatz-and-tom-n)